# How to disable Apple Pay option for some countries

Tags: ios, payment, applepay

We are offering purchases from our app and we are implementing Apple Pay as an option. We will be limiting Apple Pay service to only US and UK users - so simply hiding / showing Apple Pay button. Is this against Apple policies or is it allowed?

**EDIT**
Lets say we limit usage to US and UK. Is there any proper way to check if users come from that regions? I had in mind using Localisation (checking for preferred language and checking for currency). Or is there any better way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is for programming, not law questions.

Comment: @madhead please check comment in answer below. It is programming related.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an English expert, but right now this questions looks like law / legal related one. IMHO, programming question should ask "how do I disable Apple Pay based on user's region", not asking if it is ok due to some policies.

Comment: Good point. I changed content but left title the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think apple will reject unless you are not providing enough information on the purchase.

[Appstore Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#apple-pay) does not mention about hiding and enabling buttons but you can read the detailed [apple pay user interface guidelines here](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Apple-Pay-Identity-Guidelines.pdf)

Comment: What about checking for certain regions? Lets say we will only allow US and UK users to be able to use Apple Pay. What would be the best way to check that? I have in mind localization (preferred language and currency) or is there any other better way?